# htaccess RewriteRule in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I got this problem with htaccess. I use CodeIgniter and I removed 'index.php' from link:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This works great.

But now, I have got an older web with older links like this:

http://www.example.com/index.php/about_us/article/70,about-us

They are indexed by Google. I would like to redirect them to new structure of link.

I need to change htaccess, so above link redirects to a link that looks like this:

http://www.example.com/en/about_us/70,about-us

The '**index.php**' is removed and thats ok.
The 'article' does not always show in link, just in some links, but it is always a segment.
And I have to add 'en' (lang) in front of all.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try these;

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

routes.php

```
$route["about_us/(:any)"] = "about_us/article/$1";
```

for more information about url routing:
[URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: but in web lang is there only in google lang is not present. so i will get double lang like:

en/en/...



and in routs i got rewrite globaly cause 'about_us' is just one of meny generated dinamicly sgements.

So i nead something only with htacces and rewrite condisions i gues

Comment: Noup. this is not so simple. I whant only the google links to be redirected. links in web are ok and they nead to work like they are now.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close (untested, just thrown together for you). You may want to adjust the first rule to check if the `en` segment exists, because if it does, you'll end up with doubles in the redirected URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect any URI's starting with "index.php" to new URI
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]

# Route URI's to index.php front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```